# Retrieve attributes from the tag that imported the script

Tags: javascript, attributes, custom-data-attribute

```
<script data-src="scripts/" src="scripts/myscript.js"></script>
```

from within `myscript.js` how do i retrieve `data-src`? assume that there are also a lot of scripts loaded in the same format as this and that `myscript.js` does not know anything besides the fact that it's going to get the attribute `data-src`

is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to directly access it. You can loop through all the script elements until you find one with `src` containing the expected file name, and then check that script element's `data-src` property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this because your script will be the last `script` element found by `getElementsByTagName()`, until the next `script` is loaded when that one will become the last and so on.

```
var scriptList = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

var me = scriptList[scriptList.length-1];

var mySrc = me.getAttribute('data-src');
```

Answer (score 1):

If its the data-src attribute of a particulr script tag, I'd put an Id on the tag, and get it through the Id.

```
<script id='DataSrcScript' data-src="scripts/" src="scripts/myscript.js"></script>

var dataSrc = document.getElementById('DataSrcScript').getAttribute('data-src');
```